# I'm trying to run a line of code that imports the function to read a csv file as a functional dataframe but i'm getting an error

Tags: python, sktime

I'm trying to load a functional dataset about weather and run the MFPCA method on it.

This is my code:

```
from FDApy.misc.loader import read_csv
```

And the error is:

```
No module named 'sktime.utils.load_data'
```

Comment: Please add a larger code excerpt in order to help with answering your question.

Comment: I've already  installed FDApy and sktime modules and wrote these lines of codes:                                        from FDApy.representation.functional_data import MultivariateFunctionalData
from FDApy.preprocessing.dim_reduction.fpca import MFPCA
from FDApy.visualization.plot import plot
from FDApy.misc.loader import read_csv                             but i've got an error for the last line of code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.